# Using printf in debug mode with IAR and ST-LINK/V2 on the STM32G blocks the serial ports

Tags: c, serial-port, printf, stm32

I'm trying to debug my code on an STM32G0B0VE with IAR 9.10 using the `printf` statments. I've imported `#include <stdio.h>` in my project and under *project - options - general options - library configuration* I've selected ***semihosted***

The `printf` works fine and I'm able to see the messages in debug via I/O monitor. The issue is that it seems that the `printf` is blocking the firmware execution. For istance a string of 50 characters takes between 5 and 6 seconds to appear completly on my I/O monitor. During this period the uC seems blocked waiting the full string is trasmitted.

I manage the other serial communications with `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` and `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` to trasmit in an non-blocking way.

Is there a way to execute the `printf` in a non blocking mode maybe using `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` and setting the right UART port used by the ST-LINK/V2

Comment: does `5/6` mean `5` to `6` seconds or `0.8333` seconds?  Have you tried alternatives like `fputs(buf, stdout)`?

Comment: @ryyker up to `6`s. I fixed to make it more clear

Comment: Not sure if a [mcve] would help here, but it sure would not hurt.  Your explanation is not bad, but code is way better.   I would be careful though to work it so that your code example (should you decide to go that route) focus on the _minimal_ part.  i.e. cut out stuff that is not relevant to the problem you are seeing, but still allows a compile.

Comment: NicoCaldo, Posting the true code used would help  vs just lightly describing code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the main issue is that the code is too wide and heavy to be posted unfortunately. I would have added it right away to the question if it was possible to create a reproducible example

Comment: I guess the biggest issue here is that `printf` is, in its essence, blocking. @NicoCaldo you should consider looking into `non blocking IO`.

Comment: printf is cumbersome and very much unsuitable for embedded systems, even for debug/testing purposes. I would recommend to invest in a proper ICD debugger instead.

Comment: @WilkMaia I'm also using `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart, tx_packet, lenght_packet)` to trasmit to other serial ports in a non blocking manner but I do not know if it's usable to send my strings in debug

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with the platform in which you're developing but, on a generic stand, I don't see why that would be an issue. It wouldn't be as simple as a `printf` call -- you'd need to send the string using that protocol instead of a simple list of characters -- but I don't think it'd be that much of an issue. What you might want to evaluate is whether that would be **practical** (i.e. would you get info on a timely manner or when you got it it'd already be too late to act on it or extract meaningful/relevant information?) for your use case.